# Getting error message on below VBA to get reference of a cell along with formatting

Tags: excel, vba, reference

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
 With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If .Range("A1").Value2 <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Range("A1").Copy (.Range("E2"))
    End If
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the brackets around `(.Range("E2"))`

Comment: Please, get into the habit of indenting your code. It's much easier to read.

Comment: What error message are you getting? I wonder what `On Error Resume Next` is doing

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .Range("A1").Value2 <> "" Then .Range("A1").Copy .Range("E2")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the above code. But getting "Run-time error 9. Subscript out of range."

Comment: I renamed the sheet as Sheet1. However, still getting Run-time error. Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: I dunno what to tell you then, something must be different in your code / excel environment. It's very basic code and works fine for me.